# Css not working when render view into popup

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-5

> I Do ajax call to mvc controller
>
> i render view in somefunction
>
> i return json render view to user into popup window
>
> why the render view not using the css of the page behind him

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome extensions to debug and see the styles used by the Modal window. The Modal window doesn't inherit the styles, so try giving styles separately for the modal window, or reference it separately in modal window.